# How to change page title separator in dnn?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, dotnetnuke

Currently, the default page separator in dnn page title is ">". i want to change it globally to a different separator like "|" or "-"

e.g. - "SiteName | Home " or "SiteName - Home"

how could i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this in javascript:

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/>/g,"|"); // if you want it with |
```

( or )

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/>/g,"-"); // if you want it with -
```

Put that in `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.title = document.title.replace(/>/g,"|"); // if you want it with |
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works well. so i can not do anything with friendly url or any setting in dnn?

Comment: glad to have helped ;)

Comment: Is this the only available option? This should be a standard website setting!

Answer (score 0):

The javascript solution proposed will be ok for browser display, but not ok for search engines.

Although I'm not a proponent of making change to the DNN core, but to do a more permanent solution:

1 - Open the Default.aspx.cs file from the root folder of DNN;

2 - Replace " > " by " | " or " - " - Make sure you include the [DOUBLE QUOTES] + [SPACE] + [>] + [SPACE] + [DOUBLE QUOTES] when doing the search/replace. The search will find about 4 lines that will match/replace this.

**Note:** As this is a change in a DNN core file, whenever you do an upgrade on this site you will have to re-apply this change.